# Openlayers Move geoMarker How to Ending

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

Openlayers In this case, it is possible to stop the movement not in the middle of the movement, but at the last point.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of the marker while animating is determined by the `moveFeature` function:

```
    function moveFeature(event) {
      const speed = Number(speedInput.value);
      const time = event.frameState.time;
      const elapsedTime = time - lastTime;
      distance = (distance + (speed * elapsedTime) / 1e6) % 2;
      lastTime = time;

      const currentCoordinate = route.getCoordinateAt(
        distance > 1 ? 2 - distance : distance
      );
      position.setCoordinates(currentCoordinate);
      const vectorContext = getVectorContext(event);
      vectorContext.setStyle(styles.geoMarker);
      vectorContext.drawGeometry(position);
      // tell OpenLayers to continue the postrender animation
      map.render();
    }
```

`distance==1` is where it changes direction:

```
const currentCoordinate = route.getCoordinateAt(
        distance > 1 ? 2 - distance : distance
      );
```

If you modify that to not change direction:

```
    function moveFeature(event) {
      const speed = Number(speedInput.value);
      const time = event.frameState.time;
      const elapsedTime = time - lastTime;
      distance = (distance + (speed * elapsedTime) / 1e6) % 2;
      lastTime = time;

      const currentCoordinate = route.getCoordinateAt(
        distance // don't change direction
      );
      if (distance > 1) stopAnimation(); // stop at end
      else {
        position.setCoordinates(currentCoordinate);
        const vectorContext = ol.render.getVectorContext(event);
        vectorContext.setStyle(styles.geoMarker);
        vectorContext.drawGeometry(position);
        // tell OpenLayers to continue the postrender animation
        map.render();
      }
    }
```

And change the `startAnimation` function to start at the beginning if it is at the end:

```
    function startAnimation() {
      if (distance > 1) distance=0; // restart at the beginning if at the end
      animating = true;
      lastTime = Date.now();
      startButton.textContent = 'Stop Animation';
      vectorLayer.on('postrender', moveFeature);
      // hide geoMarker and trigger map render through change event
      geoMarker.setGeometry(null);
    }
```

[image: screenshot of map with circle at end of route]
**code snippet (using the legacy build):**

```js
const center = [-5639523.95, -3501274.52];
const map = new ol.Map({
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 9,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 19,
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
  ],
});

// This long string is placed here due to code snippet limitations.
// It is usually loaded with AJAX.
var polyline = [
  'hldhx@lnau`BCG_EaC??cFjAwDjF??uBlKMd@}@z@??aC^yk@z_@se@b[wFdE??wFfE}N',
  'fIoGxB_I\\gG}@eHoCyTmPqGaBaHOoD\\??yVrGotA|N??o[N_STiwAtEmHGeHcAkiA}^',
  'aMyBiHOkFNoI`CcVvM??gG^gF_@iJwC??eCcA]OoL}DwFyCaCgCcCwDcGwHsSoX??wI_E',
  'kUFmq@hBiOqBgTwS??iYse@gYq\\cp@ce@{vA}s@csJqaE}{@iRaqE{lBeRoIwd@_T{]_',
  'Ngn@{PmhEwaA{SeF_u@kQuyAw]wQeEgtAsZ}LiCarAkVwI}D??_}RcjEinPspDwSqCgs@',
  'sPua@_OkXaMeT_Nwk@ob@gV}TiYs[uTwXoNmT{Uyb@wNg]{Nqa@oDgNeJu_@_G}YsFw]k',
  'DuZyDmm@i_@uyIJe~@jCg|@nGiv@zUi_BfNqaAvIow@dEed@dCcf@r@qz@Egs@{Acu@mC',
  'um@yIey@gGig@cK_m@aSku@qRil@we@{mAeTej@}Tkz@cLgr@aHko@qOmcEaJw~C{w@ka',
  'i@qBchBq@kmBS{kDnBscBnFu_Dbc@_~QHeU`IuyDrC_}@bByp@fCyoA?qMbD}{AIkeAgB',
  'k_A_A{UsDke@gFej@qH{o@qGgb@qH{`@mMgm@uQus@kL{_@yOmd@ymBgwE}x@ouBwtA__',
  'DuhEgaKuWct@gp@cnBii@mlBa_@}|Asj@qrCg^eaC}L{dAaJ_aAiOyjByH{nAuYu`GsAw',
  'Xyn@ywMyOyqD{_@cfIcDe}@y@aeBJmwA`CkiAbFkhBlTgdDdPyiB`W}xDnSa}DbJyhCrX',
  'itAhT}x@bE}Z_@qW_Kwv@qKaaAiBgXvIm}A~JovAxCqW~WanB`XewBbK{_A`K}fBvAmi@',
  'xBycBeCauBoF}}@qJioAww@gjHaPopA_NurAyJku@uGmi@cDs[eRaiBkQstAsQkcByNma',
  'CsK_uBcJgbEw@gkB_@ypEqDoqSm@eZcDwjBoGw`BoMegBaU_`Ce_@_uBqb@ytBwkFqiT_',
  'fAqfEwe@mfCka@_eC_UmlB}MmaBeWkkDeHwqAoX}~DcBsZmLcxBqOwqE_DkyAuJmrJ\\o',
  '~CfIewG|YibQxBssB?es@qGciA}RorAoVajA_nAodD{[y`AgPqp@mKwr@ms@umEaW{dAm',
  'b@umAw|@ojBwzDaaJsmBwbEgdCsrFqhAihDquAi`Fux@}_Dui@_eB_u@guCuyAuiHukA_',
  'lKszAu|OmaA{wKm}@clHs_A_rEahCssKo\\sgBsSglAqk@yvDcS_wAyTwpBmPc|BwZknF',
  'oFscB_GsaDiZmyMyLgtHgQonHqT{hKaPg}Dqq@m~Hym@c`EuiBudIabB{hF{pWifx@snA',
  'w`GkFyVqf@y~BkoAi}Lel@wtc@}`@oaXi_C}pZsi@eqGsSuqJ|Lqeb@e]kgPcaAu}SkDw',
  'zGhn@gjYh\\qlNZovJieBqja@ed@siO{[ol\\kCmjMe\\isHorCmec@uLebB}EqiBaCg}',
  '@m@qwHrT_vFps@kkI`uAszIrpHuzYxx@e{Crw@kpDhN{wBtQarDy@knFgP_yCu\\wyCwy',
  'A{kHo~@omEoYmoDaEcPiuAosDagD}rO{{AsyEihCayFilLaiUqm@_bAumFo}DgqA_uByi',
  '@swC~AkzDlhA}xEvcBa}Cxk@ql@`rAo|@~bBq{@``Bye@djDww@z_C_cAtn@ye@nfC_eC',
  '|gGahH~s@w}@``Fi~FpnAooC|u@wlEaEedRlYkrPvKerBfYs}Arg@m}AtrCkzElw@gjBb',
  'h@woBhR{gCwGkgCc[wtCuOapAcFoh@uBy[yBgr@c@iq@o@wvEv@sp@`FajBfCaq@fIipA',
  'dy@ewJlUc`ExGuaBdEmbBpBssArAuqBBg}@s@g{AkB{bBif@_bYmC}r@kDgm@sPq_BuJ_',
  's@{X_{AsK_d@eM{d@wVgx@oWcu@??aDmOkNia@wFoSmDyMyCkPiBePwAob@XcQ|@oNdCo',
  'SfFwXhEmOnLi\\lbAulB`X_d@|k@au@bc@oc@bqC}{BhwDgcD`l@ed@??bL{G|a@eTje@',
  'oS~]cLr~Bgh@|b@}Jv}EieAlv@sPluD{z@nzA_]`|KchCtd@sPvb@wSb{@ko@f`RooQ~e',
  '[upZbuIolI|gFafFzu@iq@nMmJ|OeJn^{Qjh@yQhc@uJ~j@iGdd@kAp~BkBxO{@|QsAfY',
  'gEtYiGd]}Jpd@wRhVoNzNeK`j@ce@vgK}cJnSoSzQkVvUm^rSgc@`Uql@xIq\\vIgg@~k',
  'Dyq[nIir@jNoq@xNwc@fYik@tk@su@neB}uBhqEesFjoGeyHtCoD|D}Ed|@ctAbIuOzqB',
  '_}D~NgY`\\um@v[gm@v{Cw`G`w@o{AdjAwzBh{C}`Gpp@ypAxn@}mAfz@{bBbNia@??jI',
  'ab@`CuOlC}YnAcV`@_^m@aeB}@yk@YuTuBg^uCkZiGk\\yGeY}Lu_@oOsZiTe[uWi[sl@',
  'mo@soAauAsrBgzBqgAglAyd@ig@asAcyAklA}qAwHkGi{@s~@goAmsAyDeEirB_{B}IsJ',
  'uEeFymAssAkdAmhAyTcVkFeEoKiH}l@kp@wg@sj@ku@ey@uh@kj@}EsFmG}Jk^_r@_f@m',
  '~@ym@yjA??a@cFd@kBrCgDbAUnAcBhAyAdk@et@??kF}D??OL'
].join('');

var route = /** @type {module:ol/geom/LineString~LineString} */ (new ol.format.Polyline({
  factor: 1e6
}).readGeometry(polyline, {
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
}));


const routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'route',
  geometry: route,
});
const startMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(route.getFirstCoordinate()),
});
const endMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'icon',
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(route.getLastCoordinate()),
});
const position = startMarker.getGeometry().clone();
const geoMarker = new ol.Feature({
  type: 'geoMarker',
  geometry: position,
});

const styles = {
  'route': new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: [237, 212, 0, 0.8],
    }),
  }),
  'icon': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 1],
      src: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v7.2.2/examples/data/icon.png',

    }),
  }),
  'geoMarker': new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({ // CircleStyle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 2,
      }),
    }),
  }),
};

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
    features: [routeFeature, geoMarker, startMarker, endMarker],
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    return styles[feature.get('type')];
  },
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

const speedInput = document.getElementById('speed');
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-animation');
let animating = false;
let distance = 0;
let lastTime;

function moveFeature(event) {
  const speed = Number(speedInput.value);
  const time = event.frameState.time;
  const elapsedTime = time - lastTime;
  distance = (distance + (speed * elapsedTime) / 1e6) % 2;
  lastTime = time;

  const currentCoordinate = route.getCoordinateAt(
    // distance > 1 ? 2 - distance : distance
    distance
  );
  if (distance > 1) stopAnimation();
  else {
    position.setCoordinates(currentCoordinate);
    const vectorContext = ol.render.getVectorContext(event);
    vectorContext.setStyle(styles.geoMarker);
    vectorContext.drawGeometry(position);
    // tell OpenLayers to continue the postrender animation
    map.render();
  }
}

function startAnimation() {
  if (distance > 1) distance = 0;
  animating = true;
  lastTime = Date.now();
  startButton.textContent = 'Stop Animation';
  vectorLayer.on('postrender', moveFeature);
  // hide geoMarker and trigger map render through change event
  geoMarker.setGeometry(null);
}

function stopAnimation() {
  animating = false;
  startButton.textContent = 'Start Animation';

  // Keep marker at current animation position
  geoMarker.setGeometry(position);
  vectorLayer.un('postrender', moveFeature);
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (animating) {
    stopAnimation();
  } else {
    startAnimation();
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Marker Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.2.2/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.2.2/dist/ol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <label for="speed">
      speed:&nbsp;
      <input id="speed" type="range" min="10" max="999" step="10" value="60">
    </label>
  <button id="start-animation">Start Animation</button>
  <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/elm-pep@1.0.6/dist/elm-pep.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```